# Why is $\int_{|z|=1} \dfrac{\log(1-az)}{z}dz = 0$ for $|a|<1$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

As the title suggests, I am a bit unsure why that is so? Log is not holomorphic so Cauchy seems a bit off.

If anyone could provide a hint that would be very appreciated.

Edit: I have tagged the question with "cauchy-integral formula" as I suspect it has something to do with it. If it is clearly wrong however, I will remove it if so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principal branch of logarithm, which I denote by $\log z$, is analytic in the disk $D(1,1)$. So $\log (1-az)$ is analytic in $D(0,\frac 1 {|a|})$ which includes the closed unit disk. Hence, Cauchy's integral formula is applicable and the value of the integral is $2\pi i$ times the value of $\log (1-az)$ at  $0$ which is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $z=x+iy$, then
\begin{align}
  log(1-az)&=log(1-a(x+iy))\\
  &=log(1-ax-i(ay))\\
&\Rightarrow \mathfrak{R}(f(z))=1-ax\geq 0 \Rightarrow x\leq\frac{1}{a} \\
&\Rightarrow \mathfrak{I}m(f(z))=0\Rightarrow y=0\\
\end{align}
[image]

then with conditions it'll verify that the domain analyticity of $f(z)$ like this in $z=0$ is  inside the curve $\gamma:=|z|=1$, so yo can apply the Cauchy integral formule.